# Trying to compile x264 on Synology DiskStation with PowerPC

Tags: powerpc, x264, synology

I'm trying to compile x264 on a Synology NAS (DS413) with powerpc cpu (e500v).
However, when I try to run the configure - script, the following error occurs (in the config.log):

```
checking whether gcc works... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
gcc conftest.c -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) -maltivec -mabi=altivec -lm -o conftest
conftest.c:1: error: AltiVec and E500 instructions cannot coexist
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
int main (void) { return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
DIED: No working C compiler found.
```

I'm 100% certain that gcc is installed and that it works. I've googled the error and it seems that this was a bug in the configure script which should have been fixed already:
[link](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=701628). It has something to do with altivec not present in the ppc hardware or something. The script should recognise this, but unfortunately it doesn't recognize it in my case. The x264 I tried to compile is the most recent one (cloned directly from github).

The error shows up regardless of which configuration-flags I set (I tried different ones, e.g. --prefix=/opt --enable-shared --disable-asm). I also tried to modify the configuration script with sed, i.e. changing this line:

```
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -maltivec -mabi=altivec"
```

to simply:

```
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
```

but then I get this error:

```
checking whether gcc works... no
Failed commandline was:
--------------------------------------------------
gcc conftest.c -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) -lm -o conftest
/opt/lib/gcc/powerpc-linux-gnuspe/3.4.6/../../../../powerpc-linux-gnuspe/lib/li$
/opt/lib/gcc/powerpc-linux-gnuspe/3.4.6/../../../../powerpc-linux-gnuspe/lib/li$
/opt/lib/gcc/powerpc-linux-gnuspe/3.4.6/../../../../powerpc-linux-gnuspe/lib/li$
/opt/lib/gcc/powerpc-linux-gnuspe/3.4.6/../../../../powerpc-linux-gnuspe/lib/li$
/opt/lib/gcc/powerpc-linux-gnuspe/3.4.6/../../../../powerpc-linux-gnuspe/lib/li$
/opt/lib/gcc/powerpc-linux-gnuspe/3.4.6/../../../../powerpc-linux-gnuspe/lib/li$
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
--------------------------------------------------
Failed program was:
--------------------------------------------------
int main (void) { return 0; }
--------------------------------------------------
DIED: No working C compiler found.
```

Any help on how to compile it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As your CPU doesn't have AltiVec support than you need to use --disable-asm and this should be enough (without need to change anything in configure script). According to what you get with this options it looks like your gcc toolchain (or at least linker) is broken. Make sure that correct versions of gcc and ld are used (i.e. not mix from different toolchains). Have you tried to compile anything else with this gcc toolchain? Btw. What is "powerpc-linux-gnuspe/lib/li$"? Or this is truncation of string than post the full config.log

Comment: Thanks for your response. You was right, I did not see the full conf.log content. I had a problem with some libraries. However, when I don't change the line CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -maltivec -mabi=altivec" to CFLAGS="$CFLAGS", I always get the error "conftest.c:1: error: AltiVec and E500 instructions cannot coexist", even when --disable-asm is specified... Doesn't that mean that the script thinks my cpu supports altivec?

Comment: With `./configure --disable-asm` it shouldn't go to the code path of `CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -maltivec -mabi=altivec"` because it is inside of `if [ $asm = auto ] ; then` and $asm should be equal "no" with --disable-asm. So make sure that you correctly call configure script and that you don't have CFLAGS incorrectly predefined in your environment.